# Any tutorials or books that teach C# the way I learned java (commandline, without intelliSense or VS)?

Tags: c#, java

I'm a good java programmer and want to learn C# (seems fun, delegates, linq, lambda expressions, access to native dlls and unmanged code etc).

Every tutorial, book seems to teach C# with Visual Studio. But at the learning state I want to write everything manually without intelliSense or project/solution etc and compile it at command prompt, the way anyone learns java.

Is there a good resource or book that teaches C# and .net this way?

Comment: Type `csc /?` at a command prompt. If you really want to learn this way, which I don't advise, then that should be all you need.

Comment: I havn't read it myself but I think possibly you are looking for CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter.  Maybe someone who has read it could answer?

Comment: @Buh Buh I'm reading it now and its good.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but IMO an IDE will help you to learn the language much more faster. You can pick a free one like Visual C# Express and SharpDevelop for Windows or MonoDevelop for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I admire your passion to work with low level command line utilities, but it's not the practical approach to .NET development. You can still pick up C# by working with the high level IDE, which is why "every" book out there is going to assume such. The bottom line is, if you ever want to become a .NET dev, you'll have to know tools like Visual Studio and more than likely ReSharper in order to be of any significant value. I'm not being a condescending pessimist here. Just letting you know that what you desire is going to have to be pursued at a more personal/individual level as opposed to being conveniently learned in a book.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that it is practical to use IDE's to develop at professional level, but while learning, I want to know which class comes from which package/module/whatever and what are the methods available in class X without the help of other tools, like I did with C, C++ and Java. I currently use MyEclipse for Java EE development but I'm glad that I learned Java using plain notepad and command prompt.

Comment: I just want to add that the CLR book by Jeffrey Richter is an excellent source for low level knowledge for .NET. He cover tons of command line utilities like al.exe, sn.exe, ildasem.exe, csc.exe, ngen.exe, etc. You get a heavy dose of the command line. You'll even work with the Windows Registry. This book taught me many advanced low level concepts in .NET. It's great. visit http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-C-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1305521592&sr=1-1 or his personal website at http://www.wintellect.com/.

Answer (score 2):

In German, there are some interesting books to find here: http://openbook.galileocomputing.de
which focus on the language, not the IDE.
You will probably prefer native english sources over automatic translations, maybe this can be useful (not really exotic, but why not, if it fits your needs):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I checked the Microsoft link and it also based on VS. Thanks anyway, its a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

While I have never doen it this way, there are a number of articles about using the command line to work with the .net framework. I know it is doable, as one of the earlier books I read gave a breif introduction to creating your typical "hello world" program using the command line.

[THIS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164014.aspx) provides some of the essentials. Further, I KNOW there are command line utilities for compiling and such - you will have to do some exploring via MSDN and Google.

Having grown up in the new, warm-and-fuzzy age of helpful IDE's, I have never done any of that (and there are times when I wish I had). In fact, I am learning Java now, and even for that, I have the Eclipse IDE. Not as helpful as what VS provides, but nonetheless . . .

Of course, one can always type the code into a text editor "off-line" so-to-speak, and then compile the text files via the command line. This will spare you the pain of intellisense, live compiler warnings, and such . .  .  ;-)

Comment: Note - I have grown up with Vb.net, and am now dabbling with C# and actively pursuing Java. I believe you will find minimal semantic differences between C# and Java. More to do with learning the different library API's . . .

Comment: Thanks. The link is good but not what I'm looking for. I know that C# and Java are similar. The problem is, when I create a new project/solution in VC# Express, it is creating so many things/files extra which I don't know what for (I can guess but...).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](http://www.computermanuals.co.uk/scripts/browse.asp?ref=115313) by Andrew Troelsen.

Chapter 2 explains building C# applications from the comand line using csc.exe. You'll get 9 pages explaining this, which is a bargan for £34!

It's mostly therory rather than code examples to work though.  So you can choose to try out your ideas in notepad or whereever you like. I think Troelsen went to some effort to not assume everyone uses Visual Studio. There's even a chapter in the appendix for working with Mono.

Also, this book is awesome, spans the whole width of C# you are ever likely to need in your work, and has had the largest single possitive effect on my programming skills.

Comment: (After reading Simon D.'s answer (+1 for him)) This book is also about the language of C#.  Which is why it might be what you are looking for. It doesn't rely on any one IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I know the command line csc.exe compiler. When I create a new project/solution in VC# Express, it is creating so many things/files, automatic System.* imports etc for me, which I want to know and manually do without GUI help.

Comment: @jojobells - I think it covers these imports too.  I will have another read when I get home.

Comment: Just checked with the 2008 edition and it shows you can import with `csc /r:System.Windows.Forms TestApp.cs`   It also covers response files so you can save a list of references.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it. CLR via C# also seems good for my requirement.